# How can a .net class libraries be protected so it cant be referenced by other applications?

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

How can a .net class library project and resulting dll be protected so it cant be referenced by other applications (.net projects) except those projects in my own solution?

Answer (score 8):

I think you can't forbid other applications to reference you library.
You can make library's classes internal and provide access to them via [InternalVisibleTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) attribute but it won't save you from reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, aku is right.  In reality if you want certain types & methods to only be accessible to one application, you're better off compiling it all into one exe & marking those types all internal.  You can then obfuscate the code to avoid the issue with reflection (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/best-net-obfuscation-toolsstrategy))

Answer (score 1):

Forgive my ignorance, but if they're all class libraries, what does the code do?  Isn't the purpose of having a dll so that the code can be referenced.

In any case if you mark everything [`internal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx) it won't be able to be accessed outside its own library

Answer (score 1):

I think what deanbates is saying is that he is trying to find a way to keep a DLL public within his own application and private for everything else