# C# mysql - decompile shows my sql connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, exe

i have made a program and when i decompiled it with a freeware program(CodeReflect) i was able to see my mysql connection string. is there a way to avoid this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to preventing decompilation of any C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276237/how-to-preventing-decompilation-of-any-c-sharp-application)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You need to have a configuration file, like appFile.config unversioned. It should be a config file which is not compiled into the project.