# C# encrypt XML and secure it from disassembling

Tags: c#, encryption

I am doing a larger application which at some point would serialize/deserialize XML files. The problem is, that I need to make some of those XML files encrypted.

Basically, the encrypted one would be made by my professor for his students. It would be like a `black-box`, so my professor prepares a class in my application, serializes it and additionally, my app would encrypt the whole XML. Then student loads the XML to the application, but they don't know what's in it. I thought about a simple encryption, AES, whatever. I would store the key to encryption/decryption as bytes in my code.

But then it came to me, that every student could go for something like `dotPeek`, or something like this, disassembly my executable and then get the key and be able to decrypt every encrypted XML file. Now that is not something I can allow.

I was searching through the internet for possible solutions to my problem, but I couldn't quite find an answer.

Can you guys think of any way of doing that kind of thing? The app would be written in C# and would be running on Windows 7/10 if that matters.

Comment: Get an ecryption key from a server

Comment: Not possible, as the computers in the lab may and possibly will be disconnected from the internet

Comment: What about just using a password the professor passes as an argument at runtime or as an environment variable, or load it from a password guarded USB stick

Comment: Yes, that is an option, but its kinda inconvenient

Answer (score 0):

If it is a multi-user application, then you need to ensure the ownership of the file by individual user authentication & authorization.

Server should be able to validate client incoming request and serve the authorized file accordingly.

Maintain different encryption keys for each user; this is to decrypt the file. Note that, having global-admin-enc-key is vulnerable in attack vector.

To prevent the code from re-engineered, you can obscure the code by obfuscation. It confuses the code for human. This thread also claims to have a protector.
[How to prevent decompilation of any C# application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276237/how-to-prevent-decompilation-of-any-c-sharp-application)

Comment: It is a single app, which is not connected to anything whatsoever and will be copied over usb stick to multiple computers

Comment: You need obfuscator\ protector.