# I can't obfuscate my program with Eazfuscator.NET

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I want to obfuscate my program, but when I do, I get the error message: "An item with the same key has already been added." But I did not add anything.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Take help of Eazfuscator.NET

Comment: Ask their support. Additionally you will see how fast they are. Or take another product, here the list: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60054/1480104