# C# Winform Application Publish with Obfuscation

Tags: c#, winforms, obfuscation, dotfuscator

I just finished to build `Winform` application and i want to send it to couple of people for testing.

I'm using `CefSharp` in my application and i want to publish it with `ClickOnce` but i want to make it harder or impossible to de-compile, From what i understand the best option is to do code `Obfuscation`.

I saw that there is existing tool in `VS2013` - `DotFuscator`.
This tool is enough? there is any other suggestion to keep my code safe as possible?

Comment: Notice that there is a list of .net obfuscators on stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/60054/1480104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every protection can be hacked, so there is no universal answer if some tool is good enough protection for your project, it depends how much time and money you expect someone to invest in hacking the app. Saying that, DotFuscator in VS2013 offers just a basic level of protection (which is kind of expected as it has the paid version too with more features).

Providing particular solution isn't allowed on this site as 'best' is opinion based so that would not be an objective answer, there are multiple solutions search and find what is the best for you.