# Obfuscation how to get good results with free tools

Tags: obfuscation

I have noticed that the Dotfuscator Community - Visual Studio (Windows) (free version) in principle hardly encrypts anything. All classes are fully visible after applying proven tool like dotPeek etc., only some lines of code outside of the classes using these classes were renamed using cryptic strings, but these were also reletively easy to trace.

Are there any recommendations for tools (ideally free) with which one can scramble the entire code relatively safely (I know, absolute safety does not exist) ?

See above, poor results with free Dotfuscator.
Expection is at least an obfuscation that is very tiring to reengineer.

Comment: Not really SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Look at this quite good list of obfuscators from [ArmDot](https://www.armdot.com/) to [Xenocode](http://www.xenocode.com/Products/Postbuild/) here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60054/1480104

Comment: Besides all of these tools, are there any other ways to make parts of my c# code "invisible" to existing tools like ILSpy etc. ? It would be sufficient to protect single methods or classes that hold critical code.