# Why does vs2008 express shows me the source code for another dll Project?

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-express, source-code-protection

i'm totally new to .net especially with c# 3.0 and i'm working on an access database wrapper application because we need to protect the password and content of the database from being directly accessed by a third party developer.

I'm currently testing to write a simple client app to trigger the functions in the dll and to my suprise, everytime i hit a bug i can see all the source codes in this project which shows the exact source code.

So i know i'm probably missing a lot of obvious stuff here, but how do i code it so that this won't happen, so we can hide the code in the dll from the third party developer? Or is this a setting thing which only happens because both projects is in my pc?

thanks :)

### Updates:

After some browsing around, i found this [previous discussion on good obfuscation tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/best-net-obfuscation-tools-strategy)
and [i try this one tool called Eazfuscator.Net](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net) and after obfuscating the dll, i try to view it again using .net reflector or debug it via vs express2008, nothing shows no more :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing the exact code because the source is on your machine, however, it will be trivial for your third-party developer to reverse engineer the code from the DLL using a tool such as [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/).  To prevent something like this, you may want to use a [code obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) utility, such as [Dotfuscator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227240.aspx) (you may want the paid version instead of the community version), to make it more difficult to reconstruct the code from the intermediate code.

Comment: @tvanfosson, ouch, so does this means i should have sticked with using vb6 to create the wrapper instead? :S