# How to force a ASP.NET User Control DLL look into Parent Project's Libraries

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have an user control (.ascx file) that references a couple of class libraries (in App_Code) and a Web Service (in App_WebReferences).

I have compiled the UC Project into a DLL so it can be used in other projects, and got 3 DLL's: The usercontrol.dll, app_code.dll and app_webreferences.dll.

The other projects that will use this User Control, already have the class libraries and Web Service reference, so I don't want to bring in the additional DLL's for app_code.dll and app_webreferences.dll from the user control project, however it won't compile otherwise.

Is there a way to force the user control DLL to look for these libraries and web service in the parent project's code and not its own DLL's?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is yes, with reflection.  Here is how to do it:  [Add a reference dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413831/c-sharp-add-a-reference-using-only-code-no-ide-add-reference-functions)