# Encrypted a project in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, licensing, obfuscation, encryption

Are there any ways to encrypted a project in ASP.NET, so my customers can not change change the function where it checks the license code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Eziriz's .NET Reactor](http://www.eziriz.com/dotnet_reactor.htm). It's pretty good at protection. From ther site:

> .NET Reactor prevents decompilation by
>   a variety of methods which convert
>   your .NET assemblies into processes
>   which no existing tool can decompile (
>   and which are also very likely to
>   prevent decompilation by any future
>   tool). .NET Reactor builds a native
>   code wall between potential hackers
>   and your .NET assemblies by producing
>   a file which cannot be understood
>   directly as CIL. Because the CIL in
>   your assembly is emitted intact only
>   at run time or design time (in a form
>   in which the source is completely
>   inaccessible), no tool is capable of
>   decompiling .NET Reactor protected
>   assemblies.
>
> The native code wall created by .NET
>   Reactor between the hacker and your
>   source includes industry leading
>   NecroBit technology, which is
>   exclusive to .NET Reactor. .NET
>   Reactor's protection has never been
>   broken since the first release in
>   2004. These technologies make reconstruction of your source code
>   more difficult by so many orders of
>   magnitude that NecroBit is by far the
>   most effective protection you can use
>   for .NET assemblies.

Comment: Hey, that's good.. So it takes your MSIL and actually compiles some of it to native code... That would certainly be effective.

Comment: Sounds like a good method. Though not 100% bulletproof, the deterence level is pretty high. Good find!

Comment: It's brilliant. Been using it for a couple years now.

Comment: The claims seem rather far-fetched when taken literally. No doubt the tool is a deterrent.

Comment: Sorry about this, I can't seem to find a way to send a message privately. Do you have any experience with their other product, Intellilock? What's the significant difference other than the native code versus the 100% managed?

Answer (score 5):

No, it is not possible.

You can implement certain things that make it more difficult for customers to reverse or alter your program, in order such that it becomes cost-prohibitive to attempt such reversing or altering. But you cannot prevent them, if they are sufficiently determined, from reversing or altering your program.

Comment: It is not very dangerous if they change the programs my really. This is the talk of CMS and webshop. But I would not want them to resell my products or to provide the further. Therefore, I wish to binne de against domains and license key.


As he mentioned a few posts below here, so I could cool if an EXE file has been modified, but the vast majority or get web host does not allow execution of EXE files. And since I do this will be products that will have several vendors to have that product, is not this very well.

What do you think is the best solution?

Comment: You have to balance how much work you put into the deterent vs chances/amount of your losses if they indeed resell your software. I do not have an answer, it really depends on hte nature of you software/business/customer etc.

Comment: My clients are businesses within the webshop for the most part. Within the CMS is the corporate and private customers. It is well to talk about a few hundred customers.

Answer (score 1):

Not if the customers are persistent and have even a modicum of skill.  Obfuscation can only get you so far.  Any .Net assembly can be decompiled.

See here for info:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210802164013/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/080404-1.aspx

***Added***

Also, see this previous question:
[.NET obfuscation tools/strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/best-net-obfuscation-tools-strategy)

Answer (score 0):

use Dotfuscator Community Edition that ships with VS. Also put checksum function to check if your EXE is changed or not.

Comment: It's a web app, no EXE. However still do-able by injecting the checksum function into onf of the core independent assembly (if any).