# How to prevent .net application to be decompiled

Tags: .net, encryption, decompiling

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the best .NET obfuscator on the market?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337134/what-is-the-best-net-obfuscator-on-the-market)
>   [Best .NET obfuscation tools/strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/best-net-obfuscation-tools-strategy)

Hi there,

I'm ending my development of a small business application, using NET 4.0.

I would like to know which tool are you using to prevent your code to be decompiled/stolen.

I know that exists a few tools in the market, but I would like to know the best ones, keeping in mind that I'm using reflection to access properties and some methods

Thanks

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337134/what-is-the-best-net-obfuscator-on-the-market http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/best-net-obfuscation-tools-strategy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805549/free-obfuscation-tools-for-net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Visual Studio's Dotfuscator.

Comment: The one that comes with VS is hardly industrial strength; besides which if he has reflection code those parts couldn't be obfuscated.

Comment: Which does not really belong to VS, it's ad-ware.

Answer (score 1):

here is no such possibility. Dotfuscated and packed application can be unpacked and undotfuscated by professional, and it can be reversed.
Any program can be hacked, any .net program can be opened, because for that normal work needed il code, which can be easily opened.

(Translated from russian by google)

Comment: I agree with you, that any  program can be hacked, but there a few things that you can make that would eliminate 70% of hackers