# Hiding information of Application in C# from Disassembler

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, disassembly

On opening my executable file in MSIL disassembler it shows information of my application(like literals, function, properties, resources,...) even after I assigned them private.

How can I hide these information from disassembler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to look for an [obfuscation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscated_code) solution.  Remember that while private members cannot be accessed by other code, they still do exist.  However, obfuscation can make it more difficult to discern what your code is doing.

Comment: +1, not too difficult if you know IL that Reflector can show lol

Answer (score 1):

An obfuscater.  The information will still be there but the names will be nonsense designed to be as confusing as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you can't.  Your best bet if you are worried about someone reverse engineering your code is to consider the following techniques:

1. [Obfuscate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/best-net-obfuscation-tools-strategy) the code
2. [Assembly encryption](http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.net+assembly+encryption) (Note: I have no experience or working knowledge of this or the details of how it works).
3. Compile to a native assembly instead of a MSIL assembly.

The last option pretty much defeats the purpose of .NET assemblies however it will be much harder to reverse engineer from the native assembly to C# code than from MSIL to C#.  The reality is though that if someone has your DLL(s) then given enough effort and/or time the original (or fairly close) source can be developed.