# How to encrypt c# code so that it wont be easy to decompile and read

Tags: c#, .net, dll, compiler-construction, obfuscation

We are planning to secure our application so that it will be impossible to decompile by other programmer. I know there are tools out there that can decompile a dll and exe like JetBrains dotPeek. Is there a tool or procedure that can make this possible.

Comment: You will want to look into ".NET obfuscation". There are many StackOverflow questions relating to this topic. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/obfuscation

Comment: This question might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy

Comment: You can do more than just obfuscating to make it harder to decompile. Look at my ans

Answer (score 6):

It is impossible to make your code impossible to decompile.

Additionally, there's no such thing as "encrypting" a .NET assembly (or any binary) while still maintaining its ability to be executable.

What you're looking for is an obfuscator - a tool that mangles the code enough to make it harder for a human reader to understand. There is one called [Dotfuscator](http://www.preemptive.com/products/dotfuscator/overview).

Answer (score 0):

I use [.NET Reactor](http://www.eziriz.com/downloads.htm) which works very well. It does more than just obfuscating.

Comment: Thanks smerlung i currently downloading .Net Reactor it seems its free

Comment: it's a paid software