# .NET Obfuscator for windows

Tags: .net, obfuscation

Please recommend me strong obfuscator for .NET assembly 
For today i use .NET Reactor but i am not happy with it (to much bugs, sometimes project not working(or partial not working) after obfuscation)

Comment: See [.NET obfuscation tools/strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy?rq=1) and other questions in the "Related" sidebar.

Answer (score 4):

If money is not a problem (if you're buying it for work for example) I would recommend Agile .NET. It's not cheap but it's the best you'll find.

http://secureteam.net/obfuscator.aspx

Just my opinion.

Comment: did you recommend it because of you are already use it and it really working good?

Comment: after protect my project by full-functional 14-days trial demo version of Agile.Net with "merge assembly" option, protected file can not run :) also after i tried to defuscate protected exe((protection level is maximum)) by DotNetResolver - i can see all function names and all namespaces

Comment: Really? I actually haven't tried un-obfuscating it. I'm not sure whether the trial is any different to the full version. Also after reading your question I did a little more reading about it and found a lot of people have come to the conclusion that no obfuscater does a good enough job that no-one will be able to reverse-engineer your code. If someone wants it bad enough it will happen.

Comment: yes, sure, all obfuscation can be reversed, but if i use NET reactor for example now one known defuscator cannot reverse protected exe. it cheaper, but it can be cracked manually and has bugs... but after i try Agile, i have thing that better if i hold use Reactor :). What is good in Agile: has better support...