# what is the Best Encryption for dll file in asp.net project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, dll, encryption

i have a asp.net project and i want to encrypt my dll's files in bin bu using some thing like "obfuscator" but the problem is obfuscator is not free is there any way or any other tool can do it ?

Regards

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[.NET obfuscation tools/strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy)

[Obfuscation and Protection](http://babelfor.net/products/licensing)

[SharpObfuscator](http://sharpobfuscator.codeplex.com/)

[Obfuscar, The Open Source Obfuscator for .NET Applications](http://obfuscar.codeplex.com/)