# Accessing public members of my own confused dll

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, confuserex

I've asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26339462/how-to-prevent-an-applications-dll-to-be-stolen/26339832?noredirect=1#comment41342765_26339832) before, about protecting an application from being stolen and I've got an answer.

I decided to use *confuserEX* which is free and works fine with WPF. But when I checked the documentation, I noticed that it renames all the strings in the code with other meaningless strings.

My question is that, if any string is replaced with another meaningless string how can I used my own dll to access public members or functions of a class inside it?

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that anyone would *want* to go to the trouble of figuring out your obfuscated code to use your dll's?

Comment: Don't worry about your code getting stolen. The best you can do is to obfuscate your code, *(which you did)* but still it can be decompiled. If your code/logic is so much important, then have it on your server and expose it through a web service. Other than that you can't really do much to secure your code.

Comment: yeah because it contain some useful classes that really worse it , i think

Comment: Are you working for Google on their secret projects? I am sure that everything U wrote, has been written 100,000 times. On the matter - confuser makes decompiling impossible. Try to use decompiler on Confuser-obfuscated dll. It shows that dll is broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Public types and members are generally not obfuscated, so if there is code in your DLL that your app can call into from the outside, chances are that anyone else can call into it.  There's not much you can do about that.  If you have code that you don't want someone reverse engineering, then have that code run on a server that you control, as @Habib suggests.