# Can I compile C# DLL to native Code

Tags: c#, native-code

I have a C# Desktop app.

I load a C# DLL into this app via reflection methods.

Is there a way to compile this DLL into native code?

The ultimate aim is to protect my DLL the best way I can. I know it will not be 100% proof but I just want to not make it easy to do so.

Thanks

Comment: Why? The JIT compiles it to native code as required.

Comment: Hi @Lloyd, I must have misunderstood what I have read. I wanted to protect my DLL from DotPeek - a JetBrains app. I read that if the DLL is compiled into native it can not be decompiled easily?  I have tested this and DotPeek does disassemble my DLL. So, either it is not compiled to native code or the comment I read is inaccurate?  Still learning all this so apologies if I have this wrong :)

Comment: {appreciate your time BTW}

Comment: Which one are you trying to protect? The app or the other dll? You need to add more details to your question.

Comment: Hi @Mert, thanks for your suggestion. Will update question now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obfuscation is what you might be looking for. Please take a look at following links to arrive at a basic idea from your end, if Obfuscation meet your requirement.

[.NET obfuscation tools/strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164058.aspx

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I provided this answer as a hint based on your reply to Lloyd.

Comment: Hi, thanks for those links. i will look at them now.  I was going to obfuscate anyway. I have been using DotFusicator from Premptive solutions but DotPeek did not seem to have much problem with it..

Comment: @AndrewSimpson You cannot protect something fully. Even a `native` binary can be disassembled eventually.

Comment: Hi @Lloyd, you are quite right. I just did not want to make it dead easy for anyone. I have moved the majority of my code to a web service but I have created an encoder for mages that compresses the byte array on client before sending to my server so it has to stay client side. I am going to have to look at copyright but that is only as good if you are prepared to financially defend it.