# Can System.Environment.UserName be easily faked?

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, windowsdomainaccount

In a windows WPF desktop app I am using `System.Environment.UserName` in this way:

```
 var q = from l in db.Logins where 
                         l.WinLogin.Trim().Equals(System.Environment.UserName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                      && l.WinDomain.Trim().Equals(System.Environment.UserDomainName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                        select l.LoginID;

  var login = q.FirstOrDefault();
  if (login == null)
    /*Access rejected*/
  else
    /*Access granted*/
```

I am wondering if the content of the `System.Environment.UserName` & `System.Environment.UserDomainName` can be easiliy faked (set to someone's else account) within windows domain or not by a non administrator user. 
I hope that this authentication is OK for a normal windows app that does not require top security,  just want to make sure I did not overlook something obvious.

For instance if I create home workgroup with the same name as the windows domain has and then create a user within that workgroup and then connect using VPN to that windows domain and install the app on the home workgroup computer, will I fake theese variables and get the access or not?

Comment: Faked by whom? By the user? Of course, he can just modify your code or the .NET Framework code.

Comment: @usr But without plb files it would be quite difficult and demanding work, am I right?

Comment: Editing a .NET binary is super easy. Decompile, edit recompile for example. If your users are not capable of doing that then I guess this might be good enough... It's not real security, though.

Comment: As per this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy it should not be so simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `System.Environment` variables are for that machine only. The username and domain name can't be faked. The call is eventually handled by `ADVAPI32`, which is the Windows component in charge of internal Windows stuff.

You can't fake it using VPN or other methods either. That doesn't mean they can't get between the app and the database you are connecting to. Make sure to secure that too.

Comment: Thank you I will test it from home. The problem is, that when I run the app from home it authenticates against local user and computer name and not against VPN domain account used to log to the domain.

Comment: If you are running on your home PC, yes. It takes the home PC information, not that of the domain you are connecting to.

Comment: Checked it and could not fake it mainly because the domain name contains a dot character which is prohibited in the windows computer name, so for me this is enough.