# c# obfuscation what to exclude from project

Tags: c#, obfuscation

I started evaluating different solutions for .NET obfuscation but I cannot find any guide on what shall be excluded from obfuscation. Is there any guide on obfuscation for beginners

Comment: That would entirely depend on the obfuscation tool used..

Comment: If you obfuscate class, method or property names you can't use anything that depends on reflection or dynamic.

Comment: I use code first for database and I seem to have problems there. Any tool that I use gives the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy).
The tradeoff with obfuscation is the possible bugs in runtime vs code harder to decomplie, and most obfuscators will anyway leave the choice of what actually to obfuscate to you (with some explanations).
Now, each obfuscator comes with its documentation and each one claims to have some advantages over the other.
Just head to the site of the one you are interested in and look at the documentation. There are no rules for what to include/exclude it depends on your business needs.
Personally had a good experience with intellilock(which will just advice you in the process on what to add and what to include) but there are numerous good other choices, some of them are open source.

Comment: I also like the .net reactor. It is the best I have tried so far. Problem is they seem to no support it anymore. They dont answer any emails or phones. DOnt knwo why?