# Obfuscator tool from Microsoft

Tags: .net, security

I am looking for a Obfuscator tool for .NET 4.0 and above to secure .NET assemblies. I seen .NET Reactor, ConfuserEx etc. Is there any tool created by Microsoft itself OR Microsoft recommends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a question similar to this here:
[.NET obfuscation tools/strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/net-obfuscation-tools-strategy)

There someone mentions that there is a free obfuscator called DotObfuscator Community Edition that comes with Visual Studio. My guess is that even though it is community based it is probably compatible with Windows. There is also a pro version that appears to be very expensive.

Hope this helps.